# Saving Array ID to Database with value to each id

Tags: laravel

Good Evening.... Hope i can explain my problem correctly.
I am getting data (ID) in array and value (numbers) in controller. Now i want to save the "numbers" in each "ID".

```
       array ID ["Buffalo-01", "Buffalo-02", "Buffalo-04"] 
       Numbers - 40.
```

Want to save 40 to each ID.

Controller

```
    public function addbuffalototalmilk(Request $req )
        {
            $buffalomilking         =   Buffalodata::where('avgmilk','<>','0')->Where('status','=','Available')->count(); // MIlking Animal Nos
            $getbuffalomilkingid    =   Buffalodata::where('avgmilk','<>','0')->Where('status','=','Available')->pluck('buffaloID'); // Get Buffalo Details of Milking

            $totalmorningmilk       =   $req->get('morningtotalmilk');
            $totaleveningmilk       =   $req->get('eveningtotalmilk');

            $eachmorningmilk        =   ($totalmorningmilk / $buffalomilking);
            $eacheveningmilk        =   ($totaleveningmilk / $buffalomilking);

        
            
            
            return response ();
        }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please share the structure of `Buffalodata` table and format your code if you can, the question is a little bit hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```php
$buffalomilking = Buffalodata::where('avgmilk', '<>', '0')
    ->Where('status', '=', 'Available')
    ->count();

$getbuffalomilkingid = Buffalodata::where('avgmilk', '<>', '0')
    ->Where('status', '=', 'Available')
    ->pluck('buffaloID');

foreach ($getbuffalomilkingid as $id) {
    Buffalodata::where('id', $id)->update([
        'number' => $buffalomilking,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.... Finally its working... I made some changes and need to save data in new table.  Thanks Again....

Comment: foreach ($getbuffalomilkingid as $id ) {
                        $addmilkdata = new Buffalomilkrecord;    
                            $addmilkdata->buffaloID       =   ($id);
                            $addmilkdata->date            =   ($req->totalmilkdate);
                            $addmilkdata->milkmorning     =   ($eachmorningmilk);
                            $addmilkdata->milkevening     =   ($eacheveningmilk);
                            $addmilkdata->totalmilk       =   ($totalmilk);
                            $addmilkdata->save();
                    }